# How do I assign value with quote in angularjs with ng-init

Tags: angularjs, variables, ng-init

```
<script>
var a="what&#39;s";
console.log(a);//outputs what's;
</script>
```

But when I tried to assign that value in ng-init

```
<div ng-init="a='what&#39;s'">
```

Angular is throwing error as it is same as

```
ng-init="a='what's'"
```

So what should I do to resolve this?
(Note: I cann't do here `ng-init='a="what's"'` Because the value comes from database which may include both `'` and `"` sign.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-init="a='what\'s'">{{a}}</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope){
  
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
      <div ng-init="a='what\'s'">{{a}}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```